# Test execution halts with the xpath and unable to continue through Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriver

I'm using xpath to click an "image" that has an "onclick" attribute. I have tried a few different xpaths but I can't get it to work.

HTML:

```
<img height="16" width="16" class="rollover" alt="Copy" src="images\copy.gif" onclick="TestExtract(93, true);">
```

py Code:

```
test_csv_copy_btn = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//img[@onclick='TestExtract(93, true);']").click()
```

Comment: `TestExtract(93, true);` is `93` here is constant value? What do you mean by *"can't get it to work"*?

Comment: Well, the TestExtract is a JS function and it takes 2 arguments. I just get  Unable to locate the element.

Comment: I mean does it always looks like `TestExtract(93, true);`? Or it can be `TestExtract(12, true);` or `TestExtract(103, true);` or `TestExtract(Whatever, true);`? Try `"//img[@onclick=alt='Copy']"`

Comment: @Andersson I think you meant... `"//img[@alt='Copy']"`... or better yet, a CSS selector `img[alt='Copy']`.

Comment: "can't get it to work" is not helpful. Post the error message, etc. or describe how it's not working.

Comment: @JeffC , yeah, right. That was copy/paste typo :)

Comment: My apologies for the "crappy" asking of the question. I had to look for the frame and assign that before looking for the img. Thank you all for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your code trials, invoking `click()` on the desired element won't return anything. So assigning it to a variable will be of no use.

As per the HTML you have provided to click on the desired *image* you can use either of the following solutions:

- `css_selector`:

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_css_selector("img.rollover[alt='Copy'][src*='copy'][onclick^='TestExtract']").click()
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//img[@class='rollover' and @alt='Copy'][contains(@src,'copy')][starts-with(@onclick,'TestExtract')]").click()
  ```